# mint4win.exe doesn't run in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: linux-mint

I have been facing an issue with `mint4win.exe`. The package as a whole works since I have driven the OS live using a flash drive. I wanted to install it alongwith Windows 7 but when I try to open mint4win.exe, it doesn't runs. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a hunch: run as administrator.

Be sure to read the release notes for your Mint release. The [Mint 14 “Nadia” release notes](http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_nadia.php) mention:

> Important information
>   Mint4win
>   When installing Linux Mint with mint4win, choose loop0 for both the target partition and the grub destination.

If you're trying to install [Mint 13 “Maya”](http://linuxmint.com/rel_maya.php), note that there's a bug in the 32-bit image that makes Mint4win unusable out-of-the-box. Either use the 64-bit image or [repair the installation image before installing](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=106922).

Comment: I am trying to install the 64-bit version of Mint 14 MATE. I tried running it as administrator with no success. I thought of having a look at wubi log file but I can't find it in Temp folder. And since I am new to Linux so I don't know what dev\loop0 means and how to set it.

Comment: Thank you for the concern but I had previous wubi partitions on my hard disk! I had to    clean all  contents on the hard drive so that all the linux partitions are ensured to be deleted!